# AddReference Button Missing Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

in My Visual Studio Add Reference Button is Missing But in Visual Studio of my teammate everything is ok and I Don't Know what can I do to resolve this problem?

Photo of my VS is:
[Photo of my VS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvKfM.png)

And the Photo of my teammate VS is:
[the Photo of my teammate VS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uk1fM.jpg)

And the Visual Studio Version Of me and my Teammate is VS2019 Enterprise.
And the project Target Framework is .NetStandard 2.0

Notice That: I need exactly Add Reference Button, not Add Project Reference Button or ...

Comment: What version of VS 2019 are you both running? Go to Help -> About Microsoft Visual Studio to make sure you're running the same version. You could also try VS2022 to see if that helps

Comment: I am Using Version 16.11.9 and My teammate Using Version 16.5.0, I'm test it in Visual Studio 2022  and have the same Problem. @Steve Norwood

Comment: You say that you specifically don't want "Add Project Reference" button. What reference are you looking to add? Just trying to test it on my end but hard to test when I don't know exactly what you are trying to do. I assume you want to add COM reference?

Comment: I want To add .dll File to Assemblis section but when I Right-Click on Assemblies section  Add Reference Button Not shown.As you can see in the picture I posted, this option is not displayed for me, but it exists for my teammate. @Steve Norwood

Comment: Did my answer work for you @SENATOR? Let me know if you're still running into issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would assume that some time after VS 2019 16.5.0, Microsoft removed the "Add Reference" button that you are looking for.

If you right click from the project level, and go to Add -> Add Project Reference (I know this is specifically what you didn't ask for but stick with me):
[image: Screenshot of the project context menu, navigating to Add Project Reference]

You will then get the reference manager screen. If you then navigate to the "Browse" section, this should be the same as what your teammate gets in VS:
[image: Screenshot of the Reference Manager within Visual Studio]

I tested this out on a new project in VS2022 17.0.5 as a .NET Standard 2.0 Library and it all works as expected.